# Does this qualify as a Javascript closure?

Tags: javascript, closures

I've just started learning about closures in JS, and someone told me that I actually have written closures without realizing they were closures. I thought this was just a singleton object/class, but he thinks this is a closure:

```
var myWidget = {
    counter : 0,
    init : function() {
        myWidget.left();
        myWidget.right();
    },
    left : function() {
        // whatever
    },
    right : function() {
        // whatever
    }
}
myWidget.init();
```

Is this a closure? If not, what is it?

Comment: Well, I think technically every function in JS is a closure as it _will_ capture the state of the surrounding environment. I may be wrong though.

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/1577396) might help you to understand closures clearly.

Comment: This is neither a class nor a closure. Selected answer in wrong.

Comment: Hi Mr @Beetroot-Beetroot, no class there but definately a closure. I would hate to have been wrong all this time, please can you try and enlighten me with a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yup, it does.**

In that code sample you are:

1. Defining a plain object with some properties
2. Using a closure inside one of the properties (a function) to refer to the object you just defined.

I can see that whether you are defining `var myWidget` in global scope or inside another function, you will still be traversing up the scope chain to get a reference to `myWidget`.

If we use this [definition of closures here](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-6-closures/#closure):

```
A closure is a combination of a code block and data of 
a context in which this code block is created.
```

Or the [mozilla definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures):

```
Closures are functions that refer to independent (free) variables. In other words, 
the function defined in the closure 'remembers' the environment in which it was created.
```

When executing the code block inside `myWidget.init()` you are using a closure to refer to `myWidget` in the calls to `myWidget.left()` and `myWidget.right()` as you carry the `myWidget` variable in your context/environment (as opposed to finding it locally within the `init()` function).

In other words, when you execute `myWidget.init()` the following happens:

1. Is `myWidget` a local variable inside the current `function()` ? **NO**
2. Move up to parent scope (ie GLOBAL)
3. Is `myWidget` a variable in current (ie GLOBAL) scope? **YES --> CLOSURE USAGE**
4. Ok use this `myWidget` reference to retrieve the variable.

I hadn't ever thought of closures in global scope but it makes perfect sense that scope chaining keeps travelling all the way to up to GLOBAL, which just acts as another `function() {}` code block which wraps everything and is the ultimate source for finding the variable we are after, here is another article that supports this view:

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/11/30/is-javascripts-global-scope-really-just-a-closure/

Comment: Interesting Steven, I hadn't realized `myWidget.right()` would be creating a closure to the previously defined `myWidget`, a bit quirky IMO, but a closure nonetheless!

Comment: The closure is created inside `myWidget.init()`, thats the code block containing the previously-defined variable `myWidget`. `myWidget.left()` is just the bit of data we are referencing. Closures are a bit like debt, you can keep borrowing up the chain all the way up to the central bank.

Comment: So exactly what part is the "closure"?  If I'm understanding correctly, it sounds like "myWidget" is not a closure in and of itself, but executing "myWidget.init()" IS the closure?

Comment: I would not consider the act of creating functions in the *global* context which use *global* variables to be a closure. To my understanding, it should be a local scope that is closed over, since you have explicit control over that.

Comment: The use of variable `myWidget` inside `myWidget.init()` is a closure because that variable cannot be found inside the function `init()`, and is found instead by looking into the context where the function was created (ie a few lines above but outside the `function() {}` code block). Closure is the **act of looking into a parent context** for your variable (and finding it there).

Comment: Not by [formal defintion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)). What you are describing is just a lookup in the scope chain. The point of using closures is that the context which the function uses for looking up its variables *is not accessible* to the caller of that function

Comment: To put in into layman terms: if you are *Mr Init()* and you are told you need to use a widget for a particular job, but you dont **have** one and have to ask your boss for it (your boss is the parent context) and maybe he has to ask his boss and so on all the way to the CEO, then you'll be using a closure if you find your widget (at any level of the organization).

Comment: No. I'm a closure if my friend wants to borrow a widget which I can acquire from my boss (or the CEO), while my friend could not get it from them (e.g. cause he doesn't know them, or works elsewhere)

Comment: Hi @Bergi, I agree this is how you may want to use a closure, but its not what the closure is of itself. As per the wikipedia link, the closure is the **ability to reference the environment of the function** (that is being called).

Comment: I think [this section from the article you linked](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-6-closures/#theory-versions) explains it best. Theoretically, all JS functions are closures, but from the practical viewpoint we call only those function "closures" which *make use* of it (which is not the case here) :-)

Comment: Nice, Bergi sort of strengthens the case I made in my answer.  Frankly, I've not read up much on the formal definition, but at this point I'm going to make a plan of it!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like a closure to me.  Here would be a better example.

```
function init() {
    var counter = 0;

    return {
        inc: function() {
            counter++;
        },
        show: function() {
            return counter;
        }
    }
}
```

The closure is around the `counter` variable here.  The reason is when you say

```
var thing = init();
```

Javascript has to keep a reference to what would normally have been a local variable to the `init` function and hence destroyed after its execution.  With this setup, functions that can manipulate that local variable have been returned.

Try calling

```
thing.inc();
alert(thing.show());
thing.inc();
alert(thing.show());
```

You will see 1 and then 2 in the alerts, but remember, that's a *local* variable to `init` you're manipulating!  That's a closure.

**Edit**

Having read around a bit, it's clear that the code in question does have a closure.  The thread I most enjoyed on the topic was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).  As it turns out, what I have in my answer is one particular example of a closure, but by no means the only one.

Comment: This is a good example of how to use closures to mimic `private` properties in classic OO languages such as C# and Java. However the code in the question also qualifies as a closure.

Comment: @StevendeSalas yup, totally realized that after reading around last night.

Answer (score 0):

No closure is created in this case. Refer to this [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

> accessing variables outside of your immediate lexical scope creates a
>   closure

myWidget is defined in the global scope, so a closure is not generated for init when it accesses myWidget.

If you defined myWidget inside a function, and in init accessed variables in the outer function's scope, then a closure will be generated.

```
var myWidget = (function() {
  var number = 1;

  return {
    counter : 0,
    init : function() {
      myWidget.left();
      myWidget.right();
      number++;
    },
    left : function() {
        // whatever
    },
    right : function() {
        // whatever
    }
  }
})();

myWidget.init();
```

when you call init with the above code, a closure is created containing the variable number

Answer (score -3):

```
For implementing javascript closure you have to get plugin that will take care of all closure properties like css closure and javascript closure.

and you have to implement closure like the following example 

<g:compress>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dp.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css"/>    
</g:compress>
...
<div id="datepicker"></div>
<g:compress>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="common.js"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="closure/goog/base.js"/>
  <script>
       goog.require('goog.dom');
       goog.require('goog.date');
       goog.require('goog.ui.DatePicker');
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var dp = new goog.ui.DatePicker();
      dp.render(document.getElementById('datepicker'));
  </script>
</g:compress>
```

Comment: You're confusing Google Closure with the programming concept of a closure.